# Clearing HasFailure flag in gtest

Tags: c++, googletest

I have a Unit Test which is used to test if a function works well over a series of input:

```
TEST_F( something, something) {
  std::vector<int> inputFileNumber = { 0, 1 , 2, 3 };
  for(auto i : inputFileNumber ) {
    res = testMethodOverFile(i);
    EXPECT_NEAR(res, results[i], 0.01);
    logIfHasFailure(i);
  }
}
```

I would like to know which of the inputs are failing, so I could use ::testing::Test::HasFailure. Unfortunately, once the flag is set, I cannot clear it and all the following indexes are logged as well. 
Any ideas?

Comment: What does `logIfHasFailure()` do? Does it print to the console or to some log file? Why is print from `EXPECT_NEAR` not sufficient?

Comment: logIfHasFailure logs a message "data i has failed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use parametrized test instead:

```
TEST_P( something, something)
{
   auto i{GetParam()};
   res = testMethodOverFile(i);
   EXPECT_NEAR(res, results[i], 0.01);
}  

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Default, something, testing::Values(0, 1, 2,3 ));
```

Comment: I like this answer